# Problem when building phonegap example android app

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build android example app by using phonegap. Here are the the system details.
Operating System : Windows XP
Android Sdk : 1.5 ( Previously i had 2.2 but deleted suspecting problem was with that)
Ruby : 1.9.1-p430
Ant: 1.8.1
Java JDK 5
PhoneGap 0.9.1

System Enviroment Variables

ANDROID_HOME : D:\work\android-sdk_r3-windows\android-sdk-windows
ANT_HOME : D:\work\ANT\apache-ant-1.8.1
JAVA_HOME : C:\Sun\SDK\jdk
CLASSPATH : C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\lib
Path : D:\work\android-sdk_r3-windows\android-sdk-windows;C:\Ruby191\bin;D:\work\ANT\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;D:\work\android-sdk_r3-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools;

I ran ruby script and get output as below
$ ruby ./droidgap "D:/work/android-sdk_r3-windows/android-sdk-windows" pgtest c
om.example.android.pgtest example/ "D:/work/droid_apps/output1"
Building the JAR...

BUILD FAILED
D:\work\android-sdk_r3-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\ant_rules_r3.xml:28
3: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
Creating Android project for target level 1
Adding www folder to project...
Generating manifest...
Copying over libraries and assets and creating phonegap.js...
c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1265:in `initialize': No such file or dir
ectory - D:/work/phonegap/phonegap-android/framework/phonegap.jar (Errno::ENOENT
)
        from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1265:in`copy_stream'
        from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1265:in `block in copy_file'

```
    from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1264:in `open'
    from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1264:in `copy_file'
    from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:471:in `copy_file'
    from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:392:in `block in cp'
    from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1396:in `block in fu_each_sr
```

c_dest'
        from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1410:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1394:in`fu_each_src_dest'
        from c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:391:in `cp'
        from ./droidgap:82:in`copy_libs'
        from ./droidgap:20:in `run'
        from ./droidgap:157:in`'

I even changed ant to ant.bat at one place, android to android.bat at two places in ruby script. I also set target_id = 1 which is for 1.5 sdk.

In framework/default.properties updated
target=android-3
Still getting this eror and I googled finding nothing but a hint suggesting that 2.2 might cause this problem so deleted that as well from android sdk manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself it turned out to be android sdk. I downloaded all the available sdks from android sdk manager and its working now. One more thing i observed is that in libs folder the phonegap.jar in output built the size is 0kb, I copied the phonegap.jar file created after succesful run of droidgap script in framework folder. Now I am able to run the app in emulator!

Comment: Hi kapil, can you make ur answers clear. ie. i too got phonegap.jar with size 0 , i am not clear about where it need to be copied. plz clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you used the old scripts or  the new ones, but I found success with the new scripts.

take a look at the latest stuff posted on git hub

http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android

I would also suggest looking in the [PhoneGap Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap) where others have had similar problems

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with ruby 1.9.1 . It created the jar file for me. The framework has some issues with ruby 1.9.2